MOSFET rectifier is outputting a strange waveform at higher voltages
With the help of the people who commented on my last post, I finally got my MOSFET rectifier to work! Couldn't have done it without you!
After some tests, I noticed that the waveform begins to get some weird spikes at voltages above 9.5V, and no longer looks like a rectified 3 phase AC wave form. See below:

Here's how it looks below 9V:

My first guess is that it's due to the copper traces not being tuned to the same length on my board; some are longer than others, like the phase input wires.
My second guess is that it's due to stray capacitance from the traces. (There's currently no capacitors in the circuit).
Below is the rectifier circuit. Any help is appreciated!
NOTE: The physical circuit does not contain the Zener diodes which I crossed out; I only added them in KiCad as an after-thought:


I can't discern transients.

(Seeing the Zener diodes' orientation, I wonder about the simulation results.)

Transients in an active rectifier are likely to arise from two sources:

MOSFET turn-on delay, caused by gate capacitance needing time to charge.
MOSFET turn-off delay, caused by gate capacitance needing time to discharge.

The first is a minor, likely insignificant, issue. It merely means no MOSFET is conducting for a short time, causing an abrupt cutoff in output. Filtering the output will remove such glitches -- use both electrolytic capacitors to remove low frequencies, and ceramic caps in parallel to remove the tiny glitches.
The second is a major issue, because multiple devices conduct at the same time, effectively shorting two phases as current flows from  one phase, through two on MOSFET's, and to another phase. It might already be occurring, but just for microseconds, so the devices have not been destroyed yet. However, it dissipates power in the rectifier and causes high current spikes in the 3-phase source.
It's doubtful trace length of even 30 cm (1 ft) is significant -- big power MOSFET devices are far too slow to be concerned by roughly a nanosecond time difference. Instead, consider some method to keep the devices off for an extra µs.
